# Auto-rename downloaded file based on page title?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, perl

Basically, I want to have a link to download a .zip file at the bottom of each page.  Inside that .zip file I will have a PDF file.

Any time that the .zip file is downloaded, I want its title to be the same as the page's title - plus, I want the PDF to be the same.

For example, if they downloaded from a page with the title "This Is My Page" then the .zip file should be "This Is My Page.zip" and the PDF inside should be "This Is My Page.pdf".  The PDF will have the exact *same content* regardless of which page it's downloaded from.

I'm open to any solutions whether it be PHP, Javascript, HTML, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you [force a download with PHP](http://davidwalsh.name/php-force-download), you can use `filename=` in the `Content-Disposition` header to dynamically set the download's filename.

**download_zip.php**

```
$actual_file_name = '/var/yourserver/file.zip';
$download_file_name = substr(str_replace(array('\\/|>< ?%\"*'), '_', $_GET['title'] . '.zip'), 0, 255);
$mime = 'application/zip';

header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $download_file_name .'"'); // Set it here!
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($actual_file_name));
header('Connection: close');
readfile($actual_file_name);
exit();
```

To get the page title of the last page, the easiest method would likely be passing the title as a `$_GET` variable in the download link. From the page with the download link:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/download_zip.php?title=The+Page+You+Were+Just+On">Download Zip File With This Page's Title</a>
```

This will require that you include your page title in the link, so to keep from updating the page title in two places, try using a `$page_title` variable. In the page with the download link:

```
<?php
$page_title = 'Page Title';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?= $page_title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://yoursite.com/download_zip.php?title=<?= urlencode($page_title) ?>">Download Zip File With This Page's Title</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok I just tested that and it got very very close to what I want.  However, when downloading the file it's named "dynamicfilename.zip" instead.  What would I need to change to fix that?

Comment: @user1135462 I mention this at the bottom of the answer. You need to include the page title in the download link. I've updated my answer a tad to make this clearer.

Comment: I tried linking to it just like `http://yoursite.com/download/zip.php?title=The+Page+You+Were+Just+On` to see if it would download `The+Page+You+Were+Just+On.zip` but the name still came out with `dynamicfilename.zip` instead.

Comment: @user1135462 See the edit to my answer. You need to upload the download script's code to set the filename to `$_GET['title']`.

Comment: You will need to normalise the `$download_file_name` value and make it file path safe before using it as spaces and some other chars will break the header. +1 for nice answer

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè yes this is a good point. I was considering this and then got distracted by another post. Indeed this needs to be done. I'll edit now.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: Also, NTFS and ext4 limit filenames to 255 chars.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case for the new attribute 
download introduced in HTML5

```
<a id="link" href="path/to/file.zip" >Download</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
            var sPath=window.location.pathname;
            var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') +1, sPath.lastIndexOf('.'));
            $('#link').attr("download",sPage +".zip");
    });
</script>
```

read here:
http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute

supported browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Might want to include a warning about the support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download